# How to use RTPSocket to send RTP packets

Tags: java, streaming, client-server, jmf, rtp

am relatively new to JMF but have gone through the documents and have a sufficient understanding of how it works. That been said am having some trouble implementing a the server side for RTPSockets.

After looking at their illustrations and example. I am still abit confused. Am I to develop a datasource and also datasink classes to handle the transfer? What am trying to do is stream data from my application to the underlying network and receive it back through another application. I have and understand receiving but just can't get my head around the steps involved for sending.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking at a particular example, send the link, I can check and tell you what to do.